# std::replace_if on structure

Tags: c++, structure, std

The thing what I want to do is just replacing one field of structure on the vector of structure if the condition was satisfied . So here is my code:

```
struct DataST{
    int S_num,Charge,Duplicate_Nu;
    float PEP;
    string PEPTIDE;
    vector<MZIntensityPair> pairs;
    bool GetByT(const DataST& r,int T)
    {
      switch (T)
      {
          case 1:
            return (S_num == r.S_num);
          case 2:
            return (Charge == r.Charge);
          case 3:
            return !(PEPTIDE.compare(r.PEPTIDE));
          case 4:
            return (Duplicate_Nu == r.Duplicate_Nu);
          case 5:
            return ((S_num == r.S_num)&&(Charge == r.Charge));
          default:
            return false;
      }
    }
  };
int main()
{
 .
 .
 vector<DataST> spectrums;
 .
 .
 DataST tempDT_dup;
 tempDT_dup.PEPTIDE="Test";
 replace_if(spectrums.begin(), spectrums.end(), boost::bind(&DataST::GetByT, _1,tempDT_dup,3),11);
 .
 .
}
```

So in this examle I want to change all the Duplicate_Nu of spectrums items with 11 if the PEPTIDE filed of that item is equal to "test" but I got error below while I want to use function GetByT instead of operation "="

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4985:4: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘_*first.*_gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = DataST*, _Container = std::vector, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = DataST& = __new_value’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4985:4: note: candidate is:
>   hello_pwiz/hello_pwiz.cpp:14:8: note: DataST& DataST::operator=(const DataST&)
>   hello_pwiz/hello_pwiz.cpp:14:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int DataST::* const’ to ‘const DataST&’

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem thus far is that you are trying to pass a non-copyable object by copy. This is because anything that you supply as arguments to `boost::bind()` is being copied.

```
boost::bind(&DataST::GetByT, _1,tempDT_dup,3),
                                 /|\
                                  |
  This means pass by copy. --------
```

What you have to do if you do not wish to pass by copy is to pass by pointer (copying a pointer won't do any harm). Alternatively, you may use [`boost::ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/ref.html) to pass by reference,  for example:

```
boost::bind(&DataST::GetByT, _1,boost::ref(tempDT_dup),3),
```

Another problem is that you specify `11` as the last argument to [`std::replace_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace). It is a value that an element should be replaced with (if predicate returns `true`). It should be of the same type as objects stored in your array (or be convertible to). But you cannot convert `11` (which is a plain signed integer aka `int`) to an object of type `DataST`. You need something like this:

```
vector<DataST> spectrums;
DataST tempDT_dup;
DataST replacee; // What you want to replace with...
replace_if(spectrums.begin(), spectrums.end(),
           bind(&DataST::GetByT, _1, boost::ref(tempDT_dup), 3),
                replacee);
```

Comment: @khikho: Yeap, yeap, sorry — I have extended the answer.

Comment: **UPDATE part** I can't use DataST replacee because I just want to update **one** filed of the structure which the if predicate returns true (In this case I just want to update **Duplicate_Nu**). [3 is the argument on function GetByT and it's not the replacing value]

Comment: @khikho: Then you are simply using a wrong tool for the job. Replace if replaces objects inside a container. Even though you could overload an assignment operator to make it finally work, I won't do that if I were you. Consider binding `11` as well, checking condition yourself and update internal field inside `GetByT` function (better rename it) and use that with `std::for_each`. Or simply do it without this extra mambo-jumbo — just iterator through the array. It will make your code hell of a lot simpler, cleaner and easier to read and understand (for everyone).

Comment: Do you think this approach (for_each) is practical (in terms of complexity) on not short vector (**~1,000,000 items**) ?